# Need guidance regarding Helpprovider

Tags: c#, winforms

I write the following code on my main form to show the help file when i click on F1. This works fine but i am getting it as maximized i don't want this and also only after selecting the contents on the opened one i am able to see the contents by default i am unable to view

My code is as follows

```
    private void frmMain_HelpRequested(object sender, HelpEventArgs hlpevent)
    {
        helpProvider1.SetShowHelp(this, true);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer just wrote

```
 Help.ShowHelp(this, "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\ACHWINAPP.chm");
```

it solved the issue can any one tell me about the other